# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Freaking destroy behavior ignores before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-testing

So, I'm messing around with testing user permission in me app, but this test is really weird.
Here is the before filter I'm trying to get to work in my ContentsController:

```
  before_filter :only => :destroy do |controller| 
    controller.prevent_packet_sniffing_destroy_hack(controller_name.classify.constantize)
  end
```

I'm working on getting just this one controller's set of tests to work so that I can copy the before filter into the other controllers with similar behavior

The test:

```
 should "not allow the deleting of #{plural_name} on different accounts" do
      login_as(@user)
      p = Factory(factory_name, :account => Factory(:account))

   assert_difference("#{klass}.count", 0) do
    delete :destroy, :id => p.id
    klass.find_by_id(p.id).should_not be_nil
  end
    end
```

for those interested, this is a generalized test that I run over all objects with similar functionality.
Here are the variable defined by the method parameter, 'klass'

```
  factory_name = klass.name.tableize.singularize.to_sym
  plural_name = klass.name.tableize
  singular_name = klass.name.tableize.singularize
```

the destroy method for the controller I'm trying to test:

```
 def destroy
    @content = Content.find(params[:id])

    if not has_permission_to_change?(@content)      
      flash[:error] = 'You do not have permission to delete this content.'
    else
      @content.destroy
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(contents_url) }
    end
  end
```

The two methods that do permissions testing:

```
  def prevent_packet_sniffing_destroy_hack(klass)
    if not has_permission_to_change?(klass.find(params[:id]))
      puts "should be denying access"
     # render :template => "/error/401.html.erb", :status => 401
     return false
    end
  end

  def has_permission_to_change?(object)
    if (current_user.is_standard? and object.user_id != current_user.id) or
       object.account_id != current_account.id
       return false
    else
       return true
    end
  end
```

and finally, the console output

```
Loaded suite test/functional/contents_controller_test
Started
...should be denying access
E........
Finished in 1.068664 seconds.

  1) Error:
test: destroy contents! should not allow the deleting of contents on different accounts. (ContentsControllerTest):
RuntimeError: This content should not be allowed to be deleted
```

You'll notice that in the middle of the tests, the one that fails prints "should be denying access" as in the puts in my before filter.

I've also put a puts statement right above the flash error where it says "you do not have permission to delete this content" and that gets printed.

*Note: the functionality correctly works in development mode, when actually tested with a web browser and packet interceptor.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of has_permission_to_change? ?

Comment: it returns false (checked via puts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-read your test:

```
begin
  delete :destroy, :id => p.id
  raise "This #{singular_name} should not be allowed to be deleted"
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  assert true
end
```

What you're checking there is whether or not the `destroy` action goes well. And it's always the case (unless there is no `Content` with the `id` you pass but how could it ever happen?).

**You actually don't test whether or not the object is destroyed or not.**

You should rewrite it this way:

```
should "not allow the deleting of #{plural_name} on different accounts" do
  login_as(@user)
  p = Factory(factory_name, :account => Factory(:account))
  delete :destroy, :id => p.id
  klass.name.find_by_id(p.id).should be_nil
end
```

Note that you're lacking unit tests here and you should isolate your use cases a bit more using stubs.

Comment: well, the test should not let the object be deleted, because I'm logged into as @user, and create a differ account that @user can't possible be apart of. The before filter is supposed to take care of that. And the logic is all good... but something else is happening there. I do like you suggestion about the testing though... I'll edit my post to reflect it.

Comment: you are mistaken: `having the destroy action running ok` is different from `having an object deleted`

Comment: you are right. I just thought that since it wouldn't be allow to be de deleted, it should throw RecordNotFound, and then ignore the rest of the block... idk... S