# Ruby on Rails: 2.3.8, custom before filters don't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, functional-testing

So, I've been trying to set up a before_filter for checking permissions for whether or not someone can delete an object.  But it hasn't been working... eventually I do the following:

```
   before_filter :test_hack, :only => :destroy

  def test_hack
    return false
  end
```

the destroy method here:

```
def destroy
    @content = Content.find(params[:id])

#will get rid of this when the before filter works...
# but this doesn't stop it from getting deleted either
    if not has_permission_to_change?(@content) 
      puts "This content is not gonig to get deleted"   
      flash[:error] = 'You do not have permission to delete this content.'
    else
      @content.destroy
    end
```

the failing test:

```
   should "not allow the deleting of #{plural_name} on different accounts" do
      login_as(@user)
      p = Factory(factory_name, :account => Factory(:account))

      assert_difference("#{klass}.count", 0) do
        begin
          delete :destroy, :id => p.id
          raise "program flow should not reach this message"
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
          assert true
        end
      end
```

Content belongs_to an account

console output:

```
Loaded suite test/functional/contents_controller_test
Started
This content is not gonig to get deleted 
E
Finished in 0.649422 seconds.

  1) Error:
test: destroy contents! should not allow the deleting of contents on different accounts. (ContentsControllerTest):
RuntimeError: program flow should not reach this message
```

Comment: Somebody answered your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683113/ruby-on-rails-2-3-8-freaking-destroy-behavior-ignores-before-filter

Comment: @ryeguy: Thanks, I just did ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Once again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683113/ruby-on-rails-2-3-8-freaking-destroy-behavior-ignores-before-filter/6693966#6693966), the bahavior of your test is absolutely normal:

Your line `raise "program flow should not reach this message"`will ALWAYS be executed since there is an object with the `id` you pass: you just created it

You should just keep:

```
 assert_difference("#{klass}.count", 0) do
   delete :destroy, :id => p.id
  end
```

And I an't see where your `before_filter` is useful here

Answer (score 1):

In your test,

```
delete :destroy, :id => p.id
```

won't raise any exceptions, so the execution continues normally, reaching the next line

```
raise "program flow should not reach this message"
```

and the test fails, because this is not caught.
The before_filter has nothing to do with it, according to your test output, it's not even invoked.

Comment: same answer, same time, same conclusion, +1